# Replacing a specific character between specific characters in a string

Tags: jquery, replace, character, between

I need to remove all `"\n"` between `"§"`. I could only find a solution to replace or remove everything between `"§"`. 
Could someone please help me to find a solution?

Comment: Could you show what you did (how you replaced/removed everything between §)? This might help to "fix" your problem instead of solving it completely for you.

Comment: Please take a look at my Solution in the Answers below.

Comment: Show what text you have and the desired out come, and the code that you tried that didnt work.

Comment: The entire code is too big but my solution below will get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

**The Solution:**
Remove all "\n" between "<" & ">"

```
data = data_unformed.replace(/<([^<>]*)>/g, function(data_unformed,inside){ return "<"+inside.replace(/\n/g,' ')+">" });
```